# Question about the proof of $[GF(p^n):GF(p)] = n$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, proof-explanation

> Prove that $[GF(p^n):GF(p)] = n$

The proof is:

> Since $\Bbb Z_p \oplus \Bbb Z_p \oplus \dots \Bbb Z_p$ is a vector
>   space over $\Bbb Z_p$ with $\{(1, 0, . . . , 0), (0, 1, 0, . . . , 0),
> > . . . , (0, 0, . . . , 1)\}$ as a basis, we have $[GF(p^n):GF(p)] =
> > n$.

**My question is**:  Why does it matter that $\Bbb Z_p \oplus \Bbb Z_p \oplus \dots \Bbb Z_p$ is a vector space over $\Bbb Z_p$ with $\{(1, 0,
. . . , 0), (0, 1, 0, . . . , 0), . . . , (0, 0, . . . , 1)\}$ as a basis?

Because $GF(p^n)$ is only isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p \oplus \Bbb Z_p \oplus \dots \Bbb Z_p$ when $GF(p^n)$ is a group under addition.  So technically $[\Bbb Z_p \oplus \Bbb Z_p \oplus \dots \Bbb Z_p : \Bbb Z_p] = n$ should be a correct statement because this satisfies the vector space condition.

Comment: Note that restricting the multiplication from $GF(p^n) \times GF(p^n)$ to $GF(p) \times GF(p^n)$ makes $GF(p^n)$ a $GF(p)$-vector space (with the given addition). The scalar multiplication is respected by the group-isomorphism to $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^n$, thus $GF(p^n)$ is an $n$-dimensional $GF(p)$-vector space. But, it's straightforward to see that a $d$-dimensional $GF(p)$-vector space has $p^d$ elements, whence $\dim_{GF(p)} GF(p^n) = n$ follows. This way may be more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Since $GF(p^{n})$ is finite,$[GF(p^n):GF(p)]$ is finite.Suppose$[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=m\neq n$,and then each element of $GF(p^n)$ can be uniquely expressed as $a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+\cdots +a_{m}v_{m}$,and for each $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{m}\in GF(p)$,therefore,it is the consequence that $|GF(p^n)|=p^m\neq p^n$,reached a contradiction,thus $[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$.Moreover,if field $F$,$H$ are finite,and $[H:F]=n$,then $|H|=|F|^n$.